# How insert an object inside a document using Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using Pymongo to manipulate a collection witch has a structure that looks like the following:

```
{
    Client1:{
        "_id" : "Client1"
        Project1:{
            Software1:{
                language : "Python",
                complexity : "Low"
            }
            Software2:{
                language : "C#",
                complexity : "Low"
            }
            Software3:{
                language : "Java",
                complexity : "Hard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I tryed of many ways to Update the document `Client1` inserting a new `Software`, but I could not find a way or function to do this.

So my question is: In this scope, how could I insert a new `Software` without exclude the existing items?

Here is what I was trying but didn't worked:

```
client = "Client1"
client = collection.find_one({"_id": client})

project = "Project1"

software = str(raw_input("Enter with the software to be added to project: "))

language = str(raw_input("Enter with the software language: "))

complexity = str(raw_input("Enter with the software complexity: "))

collection.update({"_id" : client["_id"], }, {"$set" : {
                                                            client[project] : {software : {"language": language, "complexity" : complexity}}
                                                        }
                                               })
```

The error that I got was: `unhashable type: 'dict'` in the line that contains `client[project] : {software : {"language": language, "complexity" : complexity}}`

Since now, thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use an unhashable variable to create a key in a dict. In this case, `client[project]` is a dict, and you are using that as a key in another dict. I think you just want your key to be `project`.

```
project : {software : {"language": language, "complexity" : complexity}}
```

Comment: It Works! Thanks a lot, now my next problem is to update the `Software` attributes, I will try to find a way.

Comment: Great, glad to hear!